# How to show files in iframe by Jquery or JavaScript and prevent to show in another page loading?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Here is my problem, I had describe in code project. When I am clicking in an icon it try to open in new page for showing image or pdf or video. But, I don't like this. I like to show that files in my iframe in same page. How can I do this ? 
 My code project link is:
[Please don't open in new page. Just stay in same page.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/598646/pdf-2cplusimageplusorplustextplusfilesplusareplusn)

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest using a plugin as it makes things easier.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Alternatively what you want is to change the `iframe src`.

Using `jQuery`, you could for example, do something like this

```
<iframe id="myframe" style="display:none" width="630" height="420"></iframe>
<div class="fileIcon"> 
    <a class="click" onClick="" rel="gallery" href="#">
      <img src="src" title="" width='100' height='100' alt="" />
    </a>
</div>
```

And JS

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  var s =  $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  $('#myframe').attr('src', s).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/9QdKN/3/)

This will get the image `src` and more it to the `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

Give your iframe a `name="myframe"` then in your target you would use `target="myframe"`